# Row span not getting applied in fullcalendar

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I am using vue-fullcalender@2.7.0 to display various events in month view in Dot net MVC application.While displaying events on calendar fullcalendar sets rowspan attribute to compensate for empty columns. The generated calendar build and css works fine when no "shared/inner layout is applied in cshtml file" but when I apply shared inner layout file, my calendar entries do not match with dates of which reason being "rowspan" property is ignored by the browser.Can anybody help to forcefully apply rowspan.

[Without inner layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7FpA.png)
[With inner layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0nRu.png)

Sample  generated by fullcalendar

```
<tr>
   <td rowspan="6"></td>
   <td rowspan="6"></td>
   <td rowspan="6"></td>
   <td rowspan="6"></td>
   <td class="fc-event-container">
      <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable" style="background-color:#ff0000;border-color:#ff0000">
         <div class="fc-content">
   <td class="image-wrapper-calendar"><img style="-webkit-user-select: none;" src="https://banyan-media-stg.s3.amazonaws.com/Media/3" width="45" height="45"></td><td><ul class="list-inline clinic-name"> <li class="clinic-location">Fri Jan 04 2019 12:27:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)</li></ul><ul class="list-inline social-icon-wrapper"><li class="social-link-tab"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" style="color:#3B5998;margin: 0 5px 0 0"></i><i class="fa fa-google" style="color:#;margin: 0 5px 0 0"></i><i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="color:#C35C28;margin: 0 5px 0 0"></i></li></ul></td></div></a></td>
   <td class="fc-event-container">
      <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable" style="background-color:#ff0000;border-color:#ff0000">
         <div class="fc-content">
   <td class="image-wrapper-calendar"><img style="-webkit-user-select: none;" src="https://banyan-media-stg.s3.amazonaws.com/Media/3" width="45" height="45"></td><td><ul class="list-inline clinic-name"> <li class="clinic-location">Sat Jan 05 2019 12:27:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)</li></ul><ul class="list-inline social-icon-wrapper"><li class="social-link-tab"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" style="color:#3B5998;margin: 0 5px 0 0"></i><i class="fa fa-google" style="color:#;margin: 0 5px 0 0"></i><i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="color:#C35C28;margin: 0 5px 0 0"></i></li></ul></td></div></a></td>
   <td class="fc-event-container">
      <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable" style="background-color:#ff0000;border-color:#ff0000">
         <div class="fc-content">
   <td class="image-wrapper-calendar"><img style="-webkit-user-select: none;" src="https://banyan-media-stg.s3.amazonaws.com/Media/3" width="45" height="45"></td><td><ul class="list-inline clinic-name"> <li class="clinic-location">Sun Jan 06 2019 12:27:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)</li></ul><ul class="list-inline social-icon-wrapper"><li class="social-link-tab"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" style="color:#3B5998;margin: 0 5px 0 0"></i><i class="fa fa-google" style="color:#;margin: 0 5px 0 0"></i><i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="color:#C35C28;margin: 0 5px 0 0"></i></li></ul></td></div></a></td>
</tr>
```

For every empty event  is generated but it is not reflected in browser when I include inner layout

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should post the relevant code and add what you have already tried that isn't working so people can better help you.

Comment: @crazymatt I have added TR code